# I'm connecting to the wrong network but my configuration seems right

Tags: truffle, infura, network, kovan, truffle-config

Trying to run `truffle console` I got this typical error:

[image]

I've checked my configuration and it seems OK to me (I don't know why truffle is trying to connect to 127.0.0.1). Here you can see my project:

[image]

As you can see, the deployment of my 5 contracts was good. Infura is also working because I'm receiving data and I'm able to see my contracts deployed on https://kovan.etherscan.io. Moreover, Metamask is also connected and working:

> Connected sites
>
> Account 1 is connected to these sites. They can view your account
> address.
>
> infura.io

Am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify the network in truffle it will default to the network named `development`. if you don't define the development network in your config file it will default to the default development network spec it has hardcoded.

to use your `kovan` network you will need to specify the network :

```
truffle console --network=kovan
```

this will work with any truffle command (compile, migrate, etc.)

Comment: It's working now. Ty man, didn't know about it (just starting with truffle).

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but... how can i see my dapp on my browser? I mean: i have all of that but now...? Because I tried localhost with the port but I think I'm doing something in a wrong way.

Comment: @Joncarre - try http://localhost:3000 - I'm guessing you are using truffle that ships with create-react-app so starting the frontend client will be a different command `yarn start`

Comment: @HAS-Jack  in my `app.js` I have my `web3.providers.httpprovider('http://localhost:7545')` but I'm trying to access to it via browser and nothing happen (Unable to connect error). By the way, do I need node running? Sorry but I'm still trying to understand all the components here. Because I thought that part is executed in Kovan (or I'm wrong?) Moreover, I'm trying to access via `https://kovan.infura.io/v3/API_KEY` cause I'm using Infura

Comment: I mean, `node.js`.

Comment: @Joncarre by default don't think truffle creates a dapp for you, so you will have to do it yourself or use an existing truffle box boilerplate project, there the docs will guide you.